# Get parameters from multiple buttons into controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display the country and year selected in the view using two different select buttons.

Country select:

```
<ul id = "countries">
   <% @countries.each do |c| %>
       <li><%= link_to c.name, {controller: "things", action: "graph", :id => c.id}, remote: true -%></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

Year select:

```
<ul id = "years">
    <% years=[2009,2010,2011,2012] %> 
   <% years.each do |y| %>
       <li><%= link_to y, {controller: "things", action: "graph", :id=> y}, remote: true -%></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

Routes:

```
get 'things/graph/:id' => 'things#graph'  #I want to specify this one for country
get 'things/graph/:id' => 'things#graph'  #I want to specify this one for year
```

Controller:

```
 def graph
    @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    @year = params[:id]
    @data = [@country, @year]
    render js: "alert('The country and year is: #{@data}')"
  end
```

After selecting the country, the resulting alert is:

```
The country and year is: [#<Country id: 41, name: "Madagascar", created_at: "2017-04-14 05:50:13", updated_at: "2017-04-14 05:50:13">, "41"]
```

The displayed year value is "41" which is the country id since I have not yet hit the year select button. I would like the controller to remember the year selected in the previous selection or use a default value if no selection has been done yet.
And when I select year 2011, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Country with 'id'=2011):
```

I want the controller to remember the country selected in the previous selection.
How can I fetch the two selections (country and year) and combine them into an array for further use?

Comment: You're using same method for fetching `year` and `country`. This is the problem. When you click `country` button it easily finds the `country` with ID, but when you click to find the `year` it was unable to find the `country` with a **year** sent as ID.

Comment: @emu If I use two different methods for each value how can I then extract the country from the country method and year from the year method and then combine them to form a 2 dimensional array? Can a method read instance variables from another method?

Comment: don't send both the ids in URL. Try to send them as parameter like: `localhost:3000/things/graph?country=12&year=2011`. Then check in the controller for both parameters.

Comment: @emo How do I specify the UI selection links in order to send them as parameters instead of links? What I currently have for the links is `<%= link_to c.name, {controller: "things", action: "country", :id => c.id}, remote: true -%>`